SVG tracks mouse issue with Javascript
I have A SVG with two eyes where each pupil tracks the mouse position.
The issue is, the two eyes acts individually and not as a group. For example if you position the cursor between both eyes, the pupil from the left goes in the right direction and the pupil from the right goes to the left direction.
What I would like to achieve is, when the cursor is positioned between (or close to) both eyes, the pupils stay in the center of the eye.


    let l1 = document.querySelector("#l1");
    let l2 = document.querySelector("#l2");
    let svg1 = document.querySelector("#svg1");
    
    const toSVGPoint = (svg, x, y) => {
      let p = new DOMPoint(x, y);
      return p.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
    };
    
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
      let p = toSVGPoint(svg1, e.clientX, e.clientY);
      l1.setAttribute('x2', p.x);
      l1.setAttribute('y2', p.y);
      l2.setAttribute('x2', p.x);
      l2.setAttribute('y2', p.y);
    });
    .container{
      width: 20em;
      height: 20em;
      margin: 200px auto;
    }
    <div class="container">
      <svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
        <ellipse cx="80" cy="45" rx="20" ry="22" stroke-width="10" stroke="#fdd176"/>
        <ellipse cx="120" cy="45" rx="20" ry="22" stroke-width="10" stroke="#fdd176"/>
        <line marker-start="url(#pupil)" id="l1" x1="80" y1="45" />
        <line marker-start="url(#pupil)" id="l2" x1="120" y1="45" />
        <defs>
          <marker id="pupil" viewBox="0 0 18 18" refX="10" refY="5" markerWidth="37" markerHeight="37" orient="auto-start-reverse">
            <circle fill="#fdd176" r="4" cy="5" cx="5" />
          </marker>
        </defs>
      </svg>
    </div>



 



Here is my codepen where you can see it live.
And another codepen where you can see the wanted result.
Thank you.

Unlike in the "wanted result" code pen, your approach using line and marker ensures that the pupil always touches the edge of the ellipsis and never "stays in the center". Do you want it to "jump" from edge to center at some point?

Yes, I think I would prefer that it jumps softly from the edge to the center when the mouse is very close to the eyes or between the eyes. Exactly as you can experience in the "wanted result".

The following solution initially places the pupils in the center of the eye and then translates them by one tenth of the distance that the mouse pointer has from the center of the SVG viewBox (which I chose to be (0, 0) for simplicity). The factor of one tenth is chosen so that when the mouse reaches the edge of the viewBox, the pupils reach the edge of the eye. Mouse movements beyond the edge of the viewBox are ignored.
Both pupils always move in parallel, like in the "wanted result" codepen.


const toSVGPoint = (svg, x, y) => {
  let p = new DOMPoint(x, y).matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
  if (p.x < -100) p.x = -100;
  else if (p.x > 100) p.x = 100;
  if (p.y < -100) p.y = -100;
  else if (p.y > 100) p.y = 100;
  return p;
};

document.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  let p = toSVGPoint(svg1, e.clientX, e.clientY);
  g.setAttribute("transform", `translate(${p.x/10} ${p.y/10})`);
});
svg {
  margin: 5pc;
}

ellipse {
  stroke: #fdd176;
  stroke-width: 10;
}

circle {
  fill: #fdd176;
}
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-100 -100 200 200">
  <ellipse cx="-20" cy="0" rx="20" ry="22"/>
  <ellipse cx="20" cy="0" rx="20" ry="22"/>
  <g id="g">
    <circle r="6" cy="0" cx="-20" />
    <circle r="6" cy="0" cx="20" />
  </g>
</svg>




Thank you @HeikoTheißen this is what I almost tried to achieve. However in your example the pupils are leaving the ellipses when the mouse is outside the viewBox. The eyes should never leave the ellipses even if the mouse position is outside the viewbox by the fact that the mouse move event is related to the whole document or body of the page. I created a codepen with your code where you can see it live.

See my augmented answer.

Thanks a lot! The updated code is great

With the technique, using the a marker, you can adjust the refX of the marker element. As a default value it is 8, but when you point in between the eyes the value need to be smaller.
This answer has been updated:
I wasn't satisfied with my original calculation (and it was also commented), so I did two things: The focus point is not the same for both eyes. So now, the eyes do not squint. The points are 20 to the left of the mouse for the left eye, and equally for the right eye, to the right. Second I did a refactoring of the calculation that calculates the refX attribute.


let l1 = document.querySelector("#l1");
let l2 = document.querySelector("#l2");
let svg1 = document.querySelector("#svg1");

const toSVGPoint = (svg, x, y) => {
  let p = new DOMPoint(x, y);
  return p.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
};

document.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  let p = toSVGPoint(svg1, e.clientX, e.clientY);
  l1.setAttribute('x2', p.x - 20);
  l1.setAttribute('y2', p.y);
  l2.setAttribute('x2', p.x + 20);
  l2.setAttribute('y2', p.y);

  let refx = 8;
  if(p.x > l1.x1.baseVal.value && p.x < l2.x1.baseVal.value){
    let distY = Math.abs(l1.y1.baseVal.value - p.y);
    if(distY < 20) refx = 5 + distY/20 * 3;
  }
  document.querySelector("#pupil").setAttribute('refX', refx);
});
.container {
  width: 20em;
  height: 20em;
  margin: 200px auto;
}
<div class="container">
  <svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
    <ellipse cx="80" cy="45" rx="20" ry="22" stroke-width="10" stroke="#fdd176"/>
    <ellipse cx="120" cy="45" rx="20" ry="22" stroke-width="10" stroke="#fdd176"/>
    <line marker-start="url(#pupil)" id="l1" x1="80" y1="45" />
    <line marker-start="url(#pupil)" id="l2" x1="120" y1="45" />
    <defs>
      <marker id="pupil" viewBox="0 0 18 18" refX="8" refY="5" markerWidth="37" markerHeight="37" orient="auto-start-reverse">
        <circle fill="#fdd176" r="4" cy="5" cx="5" />
      </marker>
    </defs>
  </svg>
</div>




Thanks @chrwahl for the example. Would it be possible that the pupils move as the shown in the wanted result? As if they were a group and not moving as two individuals objects.

@MathieuPréaud I made a matter calculation of the refX attribute. If the eyes are still moving too much, the refX could be made even smaller.

Enhancement of Heiko his answer

avoiding Global variables
removing Listener
needs more tweaking...



<moving-eyes></moving-eyes>
<moving-eyes color="lightblue"></moving-eyes>
<moving-eyes color="sandybrown"></moving-eyes>

<script>
  customElements.define("moving-eyes", class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      let color = this.getAttribute("color") || "#fdd176";
      let id = crypto.randomUUID(); // every SVG needs unique IDs
      this.innerHTML = `
<svg viewBox="-100 -100 200 200" style="height:150px;background:beige">
  <ellipse id="eye${id}" cx="-20" cy="0" rx="20" ry="22" stroke-width="10" stroke="${color}"/>
  <use href="#eye${id}" x="40"/>
  <g>
    <circle id="pupil${id}" fill="${color}" r="6" cy="0" cx="-20" />
    <use href="#pupil${id}" x="40" />
  </g>
</svg>`;
      this.svg = this.querySelector("svg");
      this.svg.addEventListener('mousemove', e => this.mousemove(e));
    }
    mousemove(e) {
      let p = (new DOMPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY)).matrixTransform(this.svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
      this.querySelector("g").setAttribute("transform", `translate(${p.x/10}, ${p.y/10})`);
    }
    disconnectedCallback() {
      removeEventListener("mousemove", this.mousemove);
    }
  });
</script>




Thank you for your help Danny. I see in your example that the pupils leaves the ellipses when the mouse is outside the viewBox. Would it be possible that they always stay inside the ellipses even if the mouse is outside the viewBox?

That is the required tweaking I mentioned (it also happens in the other answers) Need to add more lines of code to check for e.target.nodeName or attach the handler to the SVG instead of the document.. or.. you're the programmer

Minor change, limited the listener to the SVG instead of document, but you still need more code to make it perfect
